# Prove that $|G:A|=|G:B||B:A|$ for $A\subseteq B\subseteq G$

Tags: group-theory

Given $G$ a group and $A,B$ subgroups of $G$ such that $A\subseteq B\subseteq G$, I want to prove $|G:A|=|G:B||B:A|$ where these are the indexes of the respective groups.

I have been presented with a proof as follows but get stuck near to the end;

Let $Bx_i$ and $Ab_j$ be the set of distinct right cosets in $G$, $B$ respectively for some $i\in I, j\in J$.

Then $|G:B|=|I|$ and $|B:A|=|J|$.

With this set up, the proof claims that $Ab_jx_i$ are all the distinct right cosets of $A$ in $G$.

I understand how the proof has shown that these are the distinct right cosets of $A$, but do not understand the deduction that these are distinct.

This is the given argument;

Suppose $Ab_jx_i=Ab_kx_l$. As $Ab_j,Ab_k \subseteq B$, this implies $Bx_i =Bx_l$ and hence $i=l$. A similar argument is used to show $Ab_j=Ab_k$ implies $j=k$.

Surely we can have two cosets being equal to each other with distinct elements representing each coset and so why would $i=l$ here?

eg. if $G=(\mathbb Q^*, \times)$ and $H=\{-1,1\}$ then the right cosets $H(1)=H(-1)=H$.

Comment: $(\Bbb{Z},\times)$ is not a group!

Comment: Edited this, sorry I meant $\mathbb Z^*= \mathbb Z \backslash \{0\}$

Comment: $\Bbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$ is still not a group!

Comment: Is that better @Teddy38? Sorry !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essential is: if two cosets have a non-empty intersection then they are equal.

$Bx_i\supseteq Ab_jx_i=Ab_kx_l\subseteq Bx_l$ tells us that the cosets $Bx_i$ and $Bx_l$ have a non-empty intersection hence are equal.

Then $x_i$ and $x_l$ both represent the same coset, *but among all representatives $x_k$ there is only one that represents the coset* $Bx_i=Bx_l$.

We could rephrase that by saying that *among all indices $k$ there is only one such that $x_k$ represents coset* $Bx_i=Bx_l$.

This justifies the conclusion that $i=l$

Then $i=l$ and setting $x_i=x=x_j$ now from $Ab_jx=Ab_kx$ we can conclude that also $Ab_j=Ab_k$.

Then cosets $Ab_j$ and $Ab_k$ have non-empty intersection hence are equal, so that also $j=k$.

Comment: That is where I was confused; we had defined the cosets to have one representative initially and so $i=l$ holds by this, so the issue of having more than one representative is true but irrelevant here. The answer on transversals now makes more sense considering this.

Comment: Indeed initially. $\{Bx_i\mid i\in I\}$ must be looked at as a partition of $G$ where $i\neq j\implies Bx_i\cap Bx_j=\varnothing$.

Answer (score 0):

I think what the author of the proof has done is that he is implicitly (or explicitly somewhere) using transversals. Given a group $G$ and a subgroup $H$ of $G$, a transversal is a set $S\subseteq G$ such that for all cosets can be written as $gH$ for some unique $g\in S$.

Example: $G=\Bbb{Z}$ and $H=4\Bbb{Z}$. A transversal for $H$ in $G$ could be $\{0,1,2,3\}$ or $\{4, 11,-3, 10\}$.

You're right that, in general, there are quite a few elements in $G$ with $g_1H=g_2H$. All that the author has done is that they are assuming that there is an already chosen set of transversals for $A$ in $B$ (the $b_i$'s) and $B$ in $G$ (the $x_i$'s).

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by transversal? Do you mean all the cosets can be written as $gH$ for every $g \in S$?

Comment: Yes, all cosets of $H$ in $G$ can be written as $gH$ for a unique $g\in S$. So the size of $S$ is always $[G:H]$.

Answer (score 0):

I will give you an alternative proof, which is also the way Lagrange's theorem is usually proven.

Define for $x,y \in G$ the relation $\equiv$

$x \equiv y \iff x^{-1}y \in H$

It is easy to verify this is an equivalence relation $G$. In particular, this implies that the set $\{[g]\mid g \in G\}$ forms a partition of the group. So, all equivalence classes are disjunct and their union is the entire group $G$.

Now, it is easy to verify that $[g] = gH$

Hence, the cosets $\{gH\mid g \in G\}$ form a partition of the group!

It follows that:

$$G = \bigcup_{g \in G} gH$$

Let $A$ be the set of representants of **different** equivalence classes

and hence, because the cosets are disjunct:

$$|G| = \left|\bigcup_{g \in G} gH\right| = \sum_{g \in A}|gH| = \sum_ {g \in A} |H| = |A||H| =  [G:H] |H|$$

We conclude:

$$[G:H] = \frac{|G|}{|H|}$$

Now, if $A \subset B \subset G$ and $A,B$ are groups

then $A$ is a subgroup of $B$ and $B$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Hence, we have:

$$[G:B] = \frac{|G|}{|B|}$$

and $$|B:A| = \frac{|B|}{|A|}$$

and we can conclude:

$$[G:B]|B:A| = \frac{|G|}{|B|} \frac{|B|}{|A|} = \frac{|G|}{|A|} = [G:A]$$

Comment: If $G$ is infinite then this makes no sense though?

Comment: You are right. This only holds for finite groups.

Comment: Ah, is there any way to go about the case $G$ is infinite, since I had a proof similar to this in mind for $G$ a finite group?

Comment: Are A,B finite?

Comment: Again there is no restriction on $A,B$